# Can I Spawn objects in Corona SDK with different distances between them using a Horizontally Scrolling background?

Tags: android, object, coronasdk

I need to generate objects for my little character to jump over. I have the artwork for these obsticles and my character can jump and I have a scrolling background.

How can I spawn my artwork for my obsticles on my x axis with spacing inbetween them?

Can anyone provide me with some sample code or atleast try and point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. You want to use some sort of loop that generates them:
2 options you can use:

```
local function frameHandler() 
   if should_I_make_object() then
      createObstacle()
   end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", frameHandler)
```

this approach will create new objects according to frame rate. IE, lets
you create objects every 100 frames lets say. This will make levels play the
same (have the same number of obstacles) on different devices that have varied frame-rate

Option 2:

```
local function createObstacle()
   --your_create_obstacle_code()
   if game_is_still_playing() then
      timer.performWithDelay(object_spawn_delay, createObstacle)
   end
end
```

This option will create a new object every object_spawn_delay milliseconds.
This is easy to code, and is a nice solution when you need things to happen on
a time-dependent interval. But you do need code to decide if the game is still playing.
Also, be aware that if the game ends, there might still be a lingering callback to 
createObstacle() that can create nasty bugs. Make sure to do proper cleanup when
the level / game ends and be aware this callback may be an issue.